# line continuation character is not working

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I have been using fortran 77 for several months and line continuation character doesn't work sometimes.

```
    if((b1(j).eq.0d0).and.(b3(j).ne.0d0))then          
    write(22,*) a1(j),a2(j),a3(j),a4(j),a5(j),a6(j),a7(j),a8(j),
  &           a9(j),a10(j),a11(j),a12(j),a13(j),a14(j),a15(j),
  &           b3(j),0.2
    else if((b3(j).eq.0d0).and.(b1(j).ne.0d0))then
    write(22,*) a1(j),a2(j),a3(j),a4(j),a5(j),a6(j),a7(j),
  &           a8(j),a9(j),a10(j),a11(j),a12(j),a13(j),
  &           a14(j),a15(j),b1(j),b2(j)
    end if
```

This is the code and when I compile it, the compiler says that '&' is a invalid character. What I am really curious is that sometimes it works and sometimes it does not. Probably I have a basic misunderstanding in fortran syntax.

```
final.f:59:72: Error: Expected expression in WRITE statement at (1)
final.f:60:9:

    &           b3(j),0.2
         1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
final.f:63:72: Error: Expected expression in WRITE statement at (1)
final.f:64:9:

    &           a14(j),a15(j),b1(j),b2(j)
         1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

Anybody can help me?

```
    parameter(m=813,n=616)
    real*8 a5(m),a6(m),a7(m),a8(m),a9(m),a10(m),a11(m),a12(m),a13(m)
    integer*8 a1(m),a2(m),a3(m),a4(m),p1(n)
    real*8 p2(n),p3(n),p4(n),p5(n),p6(n),a14(m),a15(m)
    real*8 b1(m),b2(m),b3(m)
    character skip80*80


    open(11,file='dist.dat')

    open(12,file='mksa.dat')
    open(13,file='mksb.dat')
    open(14,file='mksc.dat')
    open(15,file='mksi.dat')

    open(22,file='ksaf.dat')
    open(23,file='ksbf.dat')
    open(24,file='kscf.dat')
    open(25,file='ksif.dat')



    read(12,*)skip80
    do i=1,m
    read(12,*) a1(i),a2(i),a3(i),a4(i),a5(i),a6(i),a7(i),
 &           a8(i),a9(i),a10(i),a11(i),a12(i),a13(i),a14(i),a15(i)
    end do

    do i=1,n
    read(11,*) p1(i),p2(i),p3(i),p4(i),p5(i),p6(i) 
    end do


    do j=1,m
    do i=1,n
    if(a1(j).eq.p1(i))then
    b1(j)=p4(i)
    b2(j)=p5(i)
    b3(j)=p6(i)


    end if


    end do

    if((b1(j).eq.0d0).and.(b3(j).ne.0d0))then          
        write(22,*) a1(j),a2(j),a3(j),a4(j),a5(j),a6(j),a7(j),a8(j)
  &              ,a9(j),a10(j),a11(j),a12(j),a13(j),a14(j),a15(j)
  &              ,b3(j),0.2
    else if((b3(j).eq.0d0).and.(b1(j).ne.0d0))then
        write(22,*) a1(j),a2(j),a3(j),a4(j),a5(j),a6(j),a7(j)
  &              ,a8(j),a9(j),a10(j),a11(j),a12(j),a13(j)
  &              ,a14(j),a15(j),b1(j),b2(j)
    end if




    end do
    end
```

Comment: Welcome. You are talking about fixed form code. In which column is the `&`?

Comment: Always use tag `fortran` for more attention. Pity you are using this old standard and not a newer one.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.It is at column 6 and the code starts from column 7 :(

Comment: Reading the error message looks like something strange at column 72 (looks OK though). Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Please also specify the compilation command.

Comment: What is the filename (in particular, the extension), and what options do you pass to the compiler?

Comment: @9769953 Looks like `final.f` from the error message

Comment: If it's `gfortran`, it may be required to use `final.f77` instead; gfortran seems to be oddly picky regarding filename extensions.

Comment: I Wouldn't expect it, seen also the error message about 72)  but otherwise the option `-ffixed-form` can be used.

Comment: i just added the full code... i compiled with the command     gfortran -o final final.f

I tried after changing the file name to .f77, but seems like it's not the problem.. thank you for helping me though

Comment: As the error message says `final.f:59:72` you should check that all your lines are of suitable length.

Comment: Compiles on my side,check for sure that all `&` are in position 6 (especially the first one). Which compiler do you use? Looks like the file is not complete as the line numbers and the code don't match.

Comment: Oh, that's probably because I erased 11 lines of  comment lines(of course starting with 'c' at the first column), I just compiled with gfortran.. is there any compiler you can recommend?

Comment: weird.. I don't see where the problem occured..

Comment: I used gfortran as well. Just compile the exact code as you posted and adjust the error messages in your post.

Comment: If I copy the code to this page http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html, some lines contain TAB before & and some lines not. Possibly related? (though this may be due to copy-pasting  to the code box above...)

Comment: I immediately suspected tabs might be involved. Do not us them in Fortran. And if you do, never use them for fixed form sources.

Comment: @roygvib, TABs in the file will definitely cause problems.  Try compiling the code with the -fcheck=all -Wall options.  This should complain if a TAB is found.

Comment: @9769953, gfortran's documentation clearly defines the meaning of a file's extension.  .f is fixed-formed source code.  One does not need to rename a file to have a .f77 extension.  In fact, gfortran will give an error with a .f77 extension (without the use an option).

Comment: @evets I've just tried compiling some minimal code (not OP's code) with TAB (and gfortran-8 -Wall), and I did get this warning "Nonconforming tab character in column 1 of line 4 [-Wtabs]" So, I guess OP can also try -Wall option..

Comment: Wow. That was the problem.. thank you everybody.. I won't use TAB anymore. Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.